# maven- eclipse - download the dependencies jars

Tags: eclipse, maven, download, nexus, build-dependencies

I would like to download projects from SVN which was already configured as maven project.

The did the following steps:

1. maven is already installed
2. the setting.xml is configured to connect to nexus via SSL
3. the SSL certificate is installed via keytool.exe -import -alias myprivatecertif -keystore

When I execute this command:

```
D:\WorkSpaces\Eclipse\Lot1WorkSpace\test-project-1>mvn eclipse:eclipse -U -X
```

I get this exception :

```
D:\WorkSpaces\Eclipse\Lot1WorkSpace\test-project-1>mvn eclipse:eclipse -U -X
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 14:51:28+0100)
Maven home: D:\Tools\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin\..
Java version: 1.6.0_37, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\jre
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from D:\Tools\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin\..\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\user\.m2\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\Users\user\.m2\repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10 for C:\Users\user\.m2\repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Using mirror central (https://v-nserver-cck.tn:533/nexus/content/groups/public) for central (http://central).
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata tn.cck.atag1_0_0:parent:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\user\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for https://v-nserver-cck.tn:533/nexus/content/groups/public
Downloading: https://v-nserver-cck.tn:533/nexus/content/groups/public/tn/cck/atag1_0_0/parent/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\fr\cck\atag1_0_0\parent\1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\resolver-status.properties
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata tn.cck.atag1_0_0:parent:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://v-nserver-cck.tn:533/nexus/content/groups
org.sonatype.aether.transfer.MetadataTransferException: Could not transfer metadata tn.cck.atag1_0_0:parent:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://v
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$3.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:930)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$3.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:920)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:669)
        at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:60)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:932)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:601)
        ... 4 more
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for https://v-nserver-cck.tn:533/nexus/content/groups/public
Downloading: https://v-nserver-cck.tn:533/nexus/content/groups/public/tn/cck/atag1_0_0/parent/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/parent-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\fr\cck\atag1_0_0\parent\1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\parent-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom.lastUpdated
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[WARNING] 'groupId' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ line 4, column 11
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ line 6, column 11
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact tn.cck.atag1_0_0:parent:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT from/to central (https://v-nserver-cck.tn:533/nexus/cont

        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:363)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:636)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultMaven.java:585)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:234)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project ${parent.groupId}.map-application:map-application-impl:${projVersion} (D:\WorkSpaces\Eclipse\Lot1WorkSpace\test-project-1\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact tn.cck.atag1_0_0:parent:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT from/to central (https://v-nserver-cck.tn:533/nexus/
org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not transfer artifact tn.cck.atag1_0_0:parent:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT from/to central (https://v-nserver-
        at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:159)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:813)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:664)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:310)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:232)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:410)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:379)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:343)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:636)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultMaven.java:585)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:234)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact tn.cck.atag1_0_0:parent:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT from/to central (https://v
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:193)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:155)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact tn.cck.atag1_0_0:parent:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT from/to central (https://v
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:951)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:941)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:669)
        at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:60)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:932)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:601)
        ... 4 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
D:\WorkSpaces\Eclipse\Lot1WorkSpace\test-project-1>
```

Comment: Did you use -keystore cacerts or is the line above garbled?

Comment: yes I used this command : keytool.exe -import -alias myprivatecertif -keystore "D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -file D:\certification

Comment: It may be useful to check if the certificate is really issued against the server address you are using in your nexus URL. Does connecting via SSL to the Nexus UI work without complaints?

Comment: I have access to nexus server from browser without problems. But I should enter login/password different from what I put in the command line of keytool.exe, Just to add that I launched cmd command line as Administrator in order to be able to install the certificate because when I launched the cmd without admin previleges it does not work. Could it be related to the setting.xml? should I specify a proxy because I'm using nexus remotely using VPN?